# Why is number of partitions accessed changing when querying for intra-month records on month partitioned table?

Tags: teradata, partition

I have a tbl that is PK'ed on pkey, and has the following Partition DDL:

```
PRIMARY INDEX ( pkey )
PARTITION BY ( RANGE_N(STRT_DT  BETWEEN '2014-12-31' AND '2020-12-31' EACH 
INTERVAL '1' MONTH ,
NO RANGE),CASE_N( some_cd = 2, some_cd = 3 , some_cd = 11, ... some_cd=199 NO CASE) );
```

There are 32 some_cds so if I am selecting for a specific date, I should expect to get 33 partitions accessed. That part works. But if I do a date range in one month, I get 66 parts. Further, if I select for month-start (09-01) to month-end (09-30) I get 99 partitions accessed. I am not sure why it would be accessing twice or three times as many parts when they should all be contained in one month part, and should have only accessed 33.

```
Explain SEL * 
FROM   db.tbl 
WHERE strt_dt between '2018-09-02' and '2018-09-04';

  1) First, we lock db.tbl for read on a reserved
     RowHash in all partitions to prevent global deadlock.

  2) Next, we lock db.tbl for read.

  3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from **66 partitions** of
     db.evnt_tbl with a condition of (
     "(db.tbl.STRT_DT <= DATE
     '2018-09-04') AND (db.tbl.STRT_DT >=
     DATE '2018-09-02')") into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built
     locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no
     confidence to be 15,582,768 rows (28,046,193,392 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 43.56 seconds.

  4) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 43.56 seconds.
```

Comment: The optimizer adds the `no range` partition when you use `between` -> 66 partitions. And the last date of a month is in the next partition. Why don't you start on the first of month: `BETWEEN '20145-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' EACH ...`?

Comment: My understanding is that I have 32 partitions plus 1 no_range part, so 33 for each month. Why is a BETWEEN when both the start and end dt are in the same month  doubling the partitions into 66?  I am looking for the answer here:  https://docs.teradata.com/reader/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/9pIDvjxUAa3X~H76w~QIkw

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined your date based RANGE_N partition as

```
STRT_DT  BETWEEN '2014-12-31' AND '2020-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

your `1 month` partitioning begins on the last day of the month. So by selecting records from the table for a full month range you are actually spanning two partitions (66 with your secondary partitioning).

This is similar to the logic used in the `EXPAND ON` clause where the date range used to define a `1 month` period is based on the start date of the date range.

You can see this by adding `PARTITION` to your `SELECT` clause to see where each record is being pulled.

As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (pkey INTEGER, somedate DATE)
PRIMARY INDEX (pkey)
PARTITION BY (RANGE_N(somedate BETWEEN DATE '2016-12-31' AND DATE '2017-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH));

INSERT INTO tmp SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date), calendar_date FROM Sys_Calendar.calendar WHERE calendar.calendar_date BETWEEN DATE '2016-12-31' AND DATE '2017-12-31';

SELECT tmp.*, PARTITION FROM tmp;
```

For `September` you'll see you span over two partitions  (9 and 10 in this example):

```
245 2017-09-01  9
246 2017-09-02  9
247 2017-09-03  9
248 2017-09-04  9
249 2017-09-05  9
250 2017-09-06  9
251 2017-09-07  9
252 2017-09-08  9
253 2017-09-09  9
254 2017-09-10  9
255 2017-09-11  9
256 2017-09-12  9
257 2017-09-13  9
258 2017-09-14  9
259 2017-09-15  9
260 2017-09-16  9
261 2017-09-17  9
262 2017-09-18  9
263 2017-09-19  9
264 2017-09-20  9
265 2017-09-21  9
266 2017-09-22  9
267 2017-09-23  9
268 2017-09-24  9
269 2017-09-25  9
270 2017-09-26  9
271 2017-09-27  9
272 2017-09-28  9
273 2017-09-29  9
274 2017-09-30  10
```

To fix this, recreate your table and use the 1st of a month to define the start date of your partitioning range:

```
STRT_DT  BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

Comment: thank you much, this is very helpful. So now I know that the end of a month is actually the start of the next month's partition. But I am still wondering why when I select for one day in September I get 33 partitions accessed, but a date range like 09-05 to 09-07 causes 66 partitions to be accessed. Shouldn't it still be 33 ?

Comment: I would think it would be 33 in that case, but perhaps the optimizer thinks otherwise. Perhaps there is some deeper darker Teradata magic happening in there.